# ReactiveUi: button bound to a ReactiveAsyncCommand gets disabled after one use

Tags: .net, wpf, reactiveui

The code is very simple. First the button is enabled. On click it gets disabled and stays that way.

```
        Command = new ReactiveAsyncCommand();
        Command
            .RegisterAsyncObservable(_ => AsyncMethod())
            .SubscribeOn(RxApp.DeferredScheduler)
            .Subscribe(value =>
                           {
                               UseValue(value);                                   
                           });
```

If the can execute param is null shouldn't CanExecute be always true? (I guess CanExecute being false causing the that the button gets disabled)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `AsyncMethod` is never returning or written incorrectly, this will happen. Can you paste in the code for it?

Also, you don't need `.SubscribeOn(RxApp.DeferredScheduler)`, it's already built-in.

Comment: You are right, the AsyncMethod was written incorrectly, I forgot calling OnCompleted - still learning RX

Comment: The reason that it's disabling by the way, is that one of the features of ReactiveAsyncCommand is that it disables the command while the operation is in progress